# mysql lleft join possible with one latest record from right table?

Tags: mysql

I do not get it anymore. For a site of our club i want to show an overview of all the pinball machines in our club. 1 have 2 tables

table 1- cabinets

```
cabid | owner | cabname |valid | description
--------------------------------------------------
1 | 3 | adams family | 1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
2 | 3 | Twilight zone | 1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
3 | 4 | AC/DC | 0 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
4 | 5 | Lord of the Rings | 1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

table 2- photos

```
photoid | cabid | ismain | photourl
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 4 | 1 | fofofmasomfsaomfosa.jpg
2 | 4 | 0 | vdsnvnds89vds8vhsds.jpg
3 | 2 | 0 | v89ahv9sdvhs,jpg
4 | 2 | 0 | fsdfhsdfhsdavs.jpg
5 | 1 | 0 | sdv8ihsda98vhdsvs.jpg

etc
etc
```

No I want in one single query an overview from all the cabinets from table 1 who are valid (valid = 1). And if there is a picture, show this one. (Not every cabinet has a photo) If a user marked a photo as the main picture, this one has to be shown, (ismain) otherwise the latest like somthing as *order by ismain DESC, photoid ASC*

i now have this

```
select c.*,p.*
from cabinets c
    LEFT JOIN photos p USING (cabid )
where c.valid = '1'
GROUP by c.cabid
order by c.cabid DESC, p.ismain DESC, p.photoid  ASC
LIMIT 5
```

But it showing the wrong photos,

Is what I want possible with 1 fast query?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a simple left join  (you are not using   aggregation function so you don't need  group by  eventually you can use distinct for avoid duplicate values)

```
select distinct c.*, p.*
from cabinets c 
LEFT JOIN photos on  c.cabid = p.cabid 
where c.valid = '1'
order by c.cabid DESC, p.ismain DESC, p.photoid  ASC
LIMIT 5
```

for performance  ..  the most important thing is the presence on correct index on the join columns

check for presence of an index for cabid in cabinets and cabid on photos

Comment: I heared a lot that you should avoid 'SELECT *' since its slowering the query ?

Comment: if the OP need  all the column .. using select * or select  .. col1, col2.   and so on is the same for performance  ..  ..a difference there si only if the OP need only some columns and these column are stored in involved  index

Comment: In this case he does not need every value from the database so i guess that you can select specific columns

Comment: the most important aspect for performance in this case is  the presence of index  on the column involved in join .. (answer  speak about this)

Answer (score 0):

Fast depends a bit on the data volume and a lot on if you have indexes in place. In general it is possible. One way is:

```
select DISTINCT c.*,p.*
from cabinets c
LEFT JOIN photos p ON c.cabid=p.cabid
where c.valid = '1'
order by c.cabid DESC, p.ismain DESC, p.photoid  ASC
LIMIT 5
```

The difference is in the removal of the `GROUP BY`. You were using the `GROUP BY` in non-ANSI mode, which has unpredictable behavior. Also I could not see any use for the `GROUP BY` with your question.

The downside of this query is that it will return first all photos for `cabid=1`, so never getting you to 2,3 etc if you have more then 5 photos for `cabid=1` already. To get 5 photos of every `cabid`, you will have to query for every `cabid` by adding a `WHERE cabid=?`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the previous answers do not seem to take into account the requirement 
for just one photo if there are multiple for a cabid. This should return the correct photo if one exists.

```
SELECT a.*
    b.*
FROM cabinets a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM photos 
    WHERE a.cabid = b.cabid 
    ORDER BY b.ismain DESC 
    LIMIT 1) b
ON a.cabid = b.cabid
WHERE a.valid = 1
ORDER BY a.cabid
```

Comment: thanks, but this gives me a: Unknown column 'a.cabid' in 'where clause' and if I use "WHERE 'a.cabid' = 'b.cabid' " it find no photos at all :(

Comment: Does the table photos have a column named ```cabid```? Is it spelled differently?